# free and malloc with NSValue and NSInvocation

Tags: objective-c

I'm making a utility to get/set property values when the property has custom-named getters and setters.  You can see the full context at line 279 [here](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter/blob/getSet/JAGPropertyConverter/JAGProperty.m#L259).  The relevant snippet is here:

```
- (id) getFrom:(id) object {
    NSMethodSignature *methodSig = [[object class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:[self getter]];
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSig];
    [inv setSelector:[self getter]];
    [inv setTarget:object];
    [inv invoke];

    if ([self isObject]) {
        id returnValue;
        [inv getReturnValue:&returnValue];
        return returnValue;
    } else {
        void *buffer;
        NSUInteger length = [methodSig methodReturnLength];
        buffer = (void *)malloc(length);
        [inv getReturnValue:buffer];
        NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:buffer objCType:[methodSig methodReturnType]];
        //FIXME: Memory leak for buffer!  But if we free it, [value getValue:] is a dangling pointer.
        //free(buffer)
        return value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the property is a scalar, I want to return an NSValue (much like Key-Value coding).  However, the return value for NSInvocation is returned by reference, and according to [the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG) (see the bottom), I can't free the memory associated with the scalar while the NSValue still exists -- but I'm returning the NSValue, so I don't know when to free the memory.

Am I reading the documentation wrong?  Does NSValue handle this automatically somehow?  Or how do I free the memory properly in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your must free `buffer`. `+valueWithBytes:objCType:` copies the buffer sent in, so you can free buffer when you are done.

You could also optionally use a `NSData` object here, like this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:length freeWhenDone:YES];
```

This will mean that when the NSData object is deallocated, so will the buffer you created.

Proof that `+valueWithBytes:objCType:` copies the buffer:

```
int *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));
buffer[0] = 50;

NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:buffer objCType:@encode(int)];

// sribble 'buffer'
buffer[0] = 1000;
free(buffer);

int test = 1000;
[value getValue:&test];

printf("%i", test);  // outputs 50
```

Comment: Ah, so I must have been reading the apple documentation wrong.  Thanks, that certainly simplifies things!

Comment: @jagill no problem! I personally didn't know the answer until I wrote my test application either!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`NSMutableData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/) instead of `malloc()`. You can allocate some memory

```
NSMutableData * dat = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];
```

and use it the same way you would a `malloc`'d chunk

```
void * buffer = [dat mutableBytes];
```

Now `dat` owns the memory, which puts it under the usual Cocoa ref-counting scheme. You can do one of two things from this point.

If this object is short-lived and won't be doing a lot of such allocations, an `NSMutableArray` ivar called `allocations` or similar can hold all the `NSMutableData` instances, and they'll be freed when the object whose method this is gets deallocated.

If you'd rather, you can tie the life of the `NSMutableData` to either the `NSValue` itself or the `NSInvocation`, as appropriate, using [associated objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW1):

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(value, &dat_key, dat, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Where `dat_key` is a `static` variable declared nearby, whose address you are using (as the docs recommend).

This makes the associator (`value` in this case) retain the data object, and release it when it itself is deallocated.

Comment: Seems like a lot more hassle than just simply freeing buffer when you are done, as NSValue copies the buffer you send in.